# RxJava: what is difference between callbacks in doOnError('callback') and subscribe(*, 'callback')

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

In my last project, I use rxJava and I realize that `observable.doOnError('onErrorCallback').subscribe(action)` and `observable.subscribe(action, 'onErrorCallback')` behave in different ways. Even from docs it's not obvious for me what's exactly the difference between them and when I should use first and second variant.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `doOnError` operator allows you to inject side-effect into the error propagation of a sequence, but does not stop the error propagation itself. The Subscriber is the final destination of the events and they 'exit' the sequence.

You can see the usefulness of `doOnError` with the following example:

```
api.getData()
.doOnError(e -> log.error(e))
.retry(2)
.subscribe(...)
```

It allows you to peek into the error but lets you retry in case of an error. With an end subscriber:

```
api.getData()
.subscribe(v -> {}, e -> log.error(e) );
```

You have to arrange the handling of the error (besides the logging) on your own way.

Comment: I was searching , i don't know for how many days until if found this simple line:.subscribe(v -> {}, e -> log.error(e) ); Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation `doOnError` does not operate by default on a particular Scheduler

Comment: This is true for subscribe() as well, but I also think is irrelevant to the OP's question.